# 4 images float center

Tags: html, css

I'm having hard time with this. I want my banner to be like this.

[image]

But my output is like this.

[image]

```css
 #banner-sp{
    display: block;
}

#banner1 img{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.ban1, .ban2{
    float: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="banner-sp">
 <div class="row" id="banner1">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" class="ban1"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="row" id="banner2">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" class="ban2"></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not able to replicate the problem. getting the first output from your code

Comment: Do you use bootstrap? if yes what version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it with this css:

Use `padding` on `img` to control the distance between the pictures.

```css
banner-sp{
        display: block;
    }

    img{
        padding: 10px;
    }

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="banner-sp">
 <div class="row" id="banner1">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" class="ban1"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="row" id="banner2">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" class="ban2"></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree with you. Using flex-box is more easier than 2 solution above

Comment: Thanks. I tried the `justify-content: center;` and its working

Comment: @Ven if you use bootstrap use this class `justify-content-center` :https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: @Ven you can also try `justify-content: space-between` if you want to have the `img`s at the edge of `.container`. Please consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Padding is not the right way. Flex-box is more convenient as Vu Luu said

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like you are using bootstrap. its easy to manage the problem with bootstrap classes. But this problem can be handle with manually. 
I replaced images path with dummy images. only for better preview.

```css
    #banner-sp{
       display: block;
    }

    #banner1 img{
       padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
   .row a{
      margin:0 5px;
      display:inline-block;
   }
```

```html
<div class="container" id="banner-sp">
        <div class="row" id="banner1">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/a6a4a6/fff"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/a6a4a6/fff" class="ban1"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="banner2">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/a6a4a6/fff"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/a6a4a6/fff" class="ban2"></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
#banner-sp{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

#banner1, #banner2{
    text-align: center;
}

 #banner1 img, #banner2 img {
   margin: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="banner-sp">
 <div class="row" id="banner1">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" class="ban1"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="row" id="banner2">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" class="ban2"></a>
 </div>
</div>
```